# Will this Step Up Converter solve my problem?

Tags: design, conversion, step-up

For a project I am doing at home, I need to convert a 5v digital output from an Arduino to a 12v digital output to power a motor. A solution I found for this is using a step up converter. The step up converter that I found is a TI LM-2577SX-ADJ/NOPB. I found this part on Bangood (link below). Based on the documentation I read, this should efficiently convert a 5v output to a 12v output, but will I be losing power in amperage. Also, will this solution work as smoothly as a regular 12v power supply would once it is set up. The motor I will use will be linked below.

Converter Link: https://usa.banggood.com/DC-DC-3V-35V-To-4V-40V-Adjustable-Step-Up-Power-Module-3V-5V-12V-To-19V-24V-30V-36V-Boost-Converter-p-1166673.html

Motor: [https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Actuator-Polarity-Switch-200LBS/dp/B073RM9XSR/ref=sr_1_11?crid=13IP5HK6VSURO&dchild=1&keywords=20+inch+linear+actuator&qid=1623193760&sprefix=20+inch+linear+ac%2Caps%2C257&sr=8-11#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073RM9XSR)

Comment: What type of motor do you wish to connect?

Comment: That's a *power* converter, not suitable for signals. And fortunately, level-shifting a signal is much easier.

Comment: This converter is efficient enough, you lose about 6% of energy for transformation only. But you must think what power rating is your motor, must be less than 80W, without implementing soft-start even less (initial current draw). If you are going to supply from USB the maximum power is 2.5W btw.

Comment: Motor’s have a dynamic load range of about 100: from start to coasting so this won’t be as good as a suitable 12V supply.

Answer (score 0):

Most motors require more power than an ardiuino GPIO line can supply.  that converter can convert 5V to 12V but your arduino probably cant putput enough 5V to run the motor.

Use something like https://www.qskj.cc/shop/product/1941680-dc-dc-step-up-down-module-xl6009-adjustable-module-qs-1212cbde-20w-79150 which has an enable input this will allow you to turn the 12v output on and off with an
arduino output while using a stonger 5V supplty to provide the power for the motor.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have 12 volts available in your application you can use the part you mentioned to generate 12 volts from a 5 volt source.

For controlling the motor the simplest solution would be to put a (N-FET) transistor in between the motor and ground and use the 5 volt logic to drive it, in other words use a low side switch.

Remember to add a fly back diode over the motor.